# changing font size and font name of range containing RTF text

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I'm dynamically generating the word document which handles lot of RTF text. I want to apply certain font type and size to particular range in the document. Following is the code I'm trying

```
initialRange.Font.Size = 12;
initialRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
start = initialRange.End;
Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, <RTF TEXT TO BE PASTED>);
initialRange.PasteSpecial(DataType: 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteRTF);
end = initialRange.End;
initialRange.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```

But it always takes the formatting of the RTF Text instead of font size and name, I'm trying to set. Can anyone help how I can maintain the RTF Text format while changing just font size and name?

Another issue I'm facing is with adding the empty line. I add following code in order to add empty line.

```
initialRange.InsertAfter(Environment.NewLine);
initialRange.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```

with above code, It does add new line but font size of this empty line is just 2. Hence, it is very less space is visible between the two lines. Is there anyway to set font size of empty line as well?

Thanks

Comment: If you are pasting as RTF, you are basically telling Word: "hey, look, I have this pre-formatted text, please take as is". It is like a `<pre>` tag in HTML. If you just want to set font and size but leave the rest as is, i.e. colour, bold, italic, etc., you need to make these changes in the RTF block *before* pasting into Word. Not sure about the 2pt line break. My best guess: the RTF block ends with a 2pt formatting.

Comment: P.S: it might also be sufficient to simply move your font name and size setting to *after* the paste...

Comment: How is `initialRange` instantiated? We need to see the *context* the code snippet is running in. It's also not clear what you expect and what you're getting - please provide more detail about that. FWIW Any content in a Word document, no matter what its source and orginal data format, is *Word content*. The original encoding is *not* retained.

Comment: Also, the second question you ask makes this "too broad". The rule is one question / Question. And also this contains too little information to understand the problem well enough.